# jquery validate date in range or empty, it is not allowed to submit empty date

Tags: jquery, validation

I used the jquery validation to check a range of date or allow an empty date with under jquery mask. It is passed on editing, but the empty date field still prompt "Require" on form submit, what can I do?

```
$.validator.addMethod("daterange", function(value, element) {
    var ymd = value.split("/");
    var d = new Date(ymd[0], ymd[1]-1,ymd[2]);
    var startDate = Date.parse('2015/01/01'),   
endDate = Date.parse('2100/12/31'), 
enteredDate = Date.parse(value);

if(value=="____/__/__")
            return true;
    else if (isNaN(enteredDate)) 
            return false;
    else if (d.getFullYear() == ymd[0] && d.getMonth() == ymd[1]-1 
&& d.getDate() == ymd[2]) 
            return ((startDate <= enteredDate) && (enteredDate <= endDate));
    else
        return false;
    },"Invalid Date" );

d1_eff_date : { required: false, daterange:true},
```

Comment: What date picker are you using?

Comment: I am not using date picker, it is jquery input mask. the problem is in jquery validation.

Comment: Are you sure the mask returns `"____/__/__"` when empty? On the plugin site it returns as `""`. try that.